# ability to add button\icon in column header of flex datagrid?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I want to display the grid control in Flex ( version 3 )

**1.** with a marker/(or)icon (which acts like a button) in each colum header of the grid.
**2.** on click of the button i want o popup a textaread to capture some comments.
**3.** on close of the popup i wan to then change the marker\icon in a way highliting it which would indicate that some comments(footnotes) are present for this column.

I am very new to flex looking at the data grid control at this point. I understand that the standard features can be easily plugged in by msxml. Do i need to write some complex action script for above feature listed?

If you have experience with any such or related encounter with flex grid, please provide some inputs it will be of great help.thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one of the way

```
<mx:DataGridColumn dataField="desc">
<mx:headerRenderer>
<mx:Component>
<mx:Image toolTip="This is a column with an image " source="@Embed(source='IconInHeader.png')" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="center"/>
</mx:Component>
</mx:headerRenderer>
</mx:DataGridColumn>
</mx:columns>
```

but there are othere ways also from http://softologia.com/node/25

Comment: thanks, I am facing one problem with this. When i click on the button  - by default the 'column sort' action also kicks in in addition my buttonClick handler is also called. Any way to avoid that ( sort action ) or I can disable the sorting completely on that column ?

Comment: you can do so by sortableColumns=”false” on DataGridColumn

Answer (score 0):

Just add sortItemRenderer="{null}" in your AdvanceDataGrid  tag and will get rid of sorting icon(like a verticle line)in your AdvanceDataGrid header.